# Yii2 model show empty logo on print_r($model->attributes). how can i get its value

Tags: php, model, yii2

i have a model in Yii2 which i have print out. i want to get value test.jpg stored in logo attribute. How can i get this value from this model. I have tried pirnt_r($model->attributes) but it return empty value in logo field. Is there any way to skip the inatail empty value of log and get the test.jpg value of logo field.

```
backend\models\UserProfiles Object
(
[logo] => 
[cover] => 
[_attributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [date_created] => 2017-04-19 08:02:29
        [status] => 1
        [logo] => test.jpg
        [cover] => test (2).jpg
        [website] => wqeqww
        [address] => qweqweqw
        [about] => qweqwe
        [phone] => qweqweq
        [full_name] => qweqwe
        [city] => qweqweq
        [country] => qweqeqe
        [profile_type] => Type 1
        [user_id] => 2
    )

[_oldAttributes:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [date_created] => 2017-04-19 08:02:29
        [status] => 1
        [logo] => test.jpg
        [cover] => test (2).jpg
        [website] => wqeqww
        [address] => qweqweqw
        [about] => qweqwe
        [phone] => qweqweq
        [full_name] => qweqwe
        [city] => qweqweq
        [country] => qweqeqe
        [profile_type] => Type 1
        [user_id] => 2
    )

[_related:yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_errors:yii\base\Model:private] => 
[_validators:yii\base\Model:private] => ArrayObject Object
    (
        [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => yii\validators\RequiredValidator Object
                    (
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 
                        [requiredValue] => 
                        [strict] => 
                        [message] => {attribute} cannot be blank.
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => id
                                [1] => user_id
                            )

                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

                [1] => yii\validators\NumberValidator Object
                    (
                        [integerOnly] => 1
                        [max] => 
                        [min] => 
                        [tooBig] => 
                        [tooSmall] => 
                        [integerPattern] => /^\s*[+-]?\d+\s*$/
                        [numberPattern] => /^\s*[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?\s*$/
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => id
                                [1] => user_id
                            )

                        [message] => {attribute} must be an integer.
                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 1
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

                [2] => yii\validators\StringValidator Object
                    (
                        [length] => 
                        [max] => 
                        [min] => 
                        [message] => {attribute} must be a string.
                        [tooShort] => 
                        [tooLong] => 
                        [notEqual] => 
                        [encoding] => UTF-8
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => address
                                [1] => about
                            )

                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 1
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

                [3] => yii\validators\FileValidator Object
                    (
                        [extensions] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => jpg
                                [1] => png
                            )

                        [checkExtensionByMimeType] => 1
                        [mimeTypes] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [minSize] => 
                        [maxSize] => 
                        [maxFiles] => 1
                        [message] => File upload failed.
                        [uploadRequired] => Please upload a file.
                        [tooBig] => The file "{file}" is too big. Its size cannot exceed {formattedLimit}.
                        [tooSmall] => The file "{file}" is too small. Its size cannot be smaller than {formattedLimit}.
                        [tooMany] => You can upload at most {limit, number} {limit, plural, one{file} other{files}}.
                        [wrongExtension] => Only files with these extensions are allowed: {extensions}.
                        [wrongMimeType] => Only files with these MIME types are allowed: {mimeTypes}.
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => logo
                                [1] => cover
                            )

                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

                [4] => yii\validators\StringValidator Object
                    (
                        [length] => 
                        [max] => 45
                        [min] => 
                        [message] => {attribute} must be a string.
                        [tooShort] => 
                        [tooLong] => {attribute} should contain at most {max, number} {max, plural, one{character} other{characters}}.
                        [notEqual] => 
                        [encoding] => UTF-8
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => date_created
                                [1] => status
                                [2] => logo
                                [3] => cover
                                [4] => website
                                [5] => phone
                                [6] => full_name
                                [7] => city
                                [8] => country
                                [9] => profile_type
                            )

                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 1
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

                [5] => yii\validators\ExistValidator Object
                    (
                        [targetClass] => backend\models\User
                        [targetAttribute] => Array
                            (
                                [user_id] => id
                            )

                        [filter] => 
                        [allowArray] => 
                        [targetAttributeJunction] => and
                        [attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => user_id
                            )

                        [message] => {attribute} is invalid.
                        [on] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [except] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [skipOnError] => 1
                        [skipOnEmpty] => 1
                        [enableClientValidation] => 1
                        [isEmpty] => 
                        [when] => 
                        [whenClient] => 
                        [_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
                            (
                            )

                        [_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => 
                    )

            )

    )

[_scenario:yii\base\Model:private] => default
[_events:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
    (
    )

[_behaviors:yii\base\Component:private] => Array
    (
    )
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see there printed is the private property _attributes part of  BaseActiveRecord, which cannot be accessed directly.
Take a look at yii\db\BaseActiveRecord class, you can see there how you can access the logo attribute.

You could try:

$model->getAttribute('logo')

Or maybe
    $model->logo

The latter should use the magic method "__get" of ActiveBaseRecord and it may work. The issue that I see is that your class has also a property named logo, which may make this complicated.

Comment: Please edit your answer to include some explanation.  Code-only answers do very little to educate future SO readers.  Your answer is in the moderation queue for being low-quality.